# How to put the reduce partitions into designed machines in hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, reduce, partition

For example:

reduce results: `part-00000`, `part-00001` ... `part-00008`,
the cluster has 3 datanodes and I want to

- put the `part-00000`, `part-00001` and `part-00002` to the `slave0`
- put the `part-00003`, `part-00004` and `part-00005` to the `slave1`
- put the `part-00006`, `part-00007` and `part-00008` to the `slave2`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work like that. A file in HDFS is not stored in any specific datanode. Each file is composed of blocks and each block is replicated to multiple nodes (3 by default). So each file is actually stored in differed nodes, since the blocks that compose it are stored in different nodes.

Quoting the [official documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html), which I advise you to read:

> HDFS exposes a file system namespace and allows user data to be stored in files. Internally, a file is split into one or more blocks and these blocks are stored in a set of DataNodes. The NameNode executes file system namespace operations like opening, closing, and renaming files and directories. It also determines the mapping of blocks to DataNodes. The DataNodes are responsible for serving read and write requests from the file system’s clients. The DataNodes also perform block creation, deletion, and replication upon instruction from the NameNode.

Seeing the partition tag in your question, it may be worth stating that the Partitioner defines in which *partition* (not datanode), each key will end up. For example, knowing that you have 9 reduce tasks (9 partitions), you may wish to evenly split the workload of each such task. In order to do that, you can define that, e.g., the keys starting with the letter "s" should be sent to partition 0 and the keys starting with the letter "a" or "b" to partition 1, etc. (just a stupid example to illustrate what a partitioner does).